# Windows Mail Crashes

Tags: windows, windows-live-mail

Windows Mail is a great application aside from it crashing when you create, forward, or reply to a message. This is a basic function that any mail manager should be able to handle.

Does anyone else have this problem? I googled it and it doesn't seem like I'm the only one.

and if you don't have a fix for this, what mail manager to you use/recommend?

I'm testing Postbox right now, I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

> Windows Mail is a great application aside from it crashing when you create, forward, or reply to a message. This is a basic function that any mail manager should be able to handle.

This is an extraordinarily provocative statement, and one that is completely unfair. You could replace "Windows Mail" with any mail manager you'd care to mention, and your statement could be true.

**On the fixing side...**

- Are there any errors in Event Viewer that provide any information?
- Is there an error message?
- Do you have the latest version of Windows Mail
- Is your computer running all the latest service packs?
- Do you run an antivirus? If so, have you disabled the outgoing message scanning (at least temporarily, since some antivirus apps can cause drama when dealing with outgoing mail)
- Are you using POP3 or IMAP? A remotely hosted IMAP can cause dramas if it's taking too long to respond (especially when combined with an overzealous antivirus)
- Which operating system are you running?

**On the reccomendation side...**

- [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) would be my first choice. It's light years ahead of any other mail application on Windows, except for Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a number of crashes recently with Windows Mail after a reported record number of Windows updates:-losing replies I was working on, not immediately deleting my individual selections in inbox and then suddenly deleting a bunch I did not want deleted. I have all the latest updates on my 2 year old Vista laptop and attribute the problem to Windows 7 fixes Microsoft is using now on Vista. I will try disabling the anti virus mail out. I am thinking of upgrading to Windows 7 but haven't yet because there is no Windows Mail. I found a fix using a Take Ownership hack fix to make it work in Vista but would that be creating problems? Microsoft would not be providing patches and fixes. I hate web based mail, so many have to buy Outlook to go with my Microsoft Office. Any input here??

Comment: Make it a separate question. This is not a forum.